# Laravel relation table user and address

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent, relation

I'm confronted to a little problem, I try to retrieve my data of table address relation with user.

In my DB addresses I have a foreign key user_id associated to users table ID.

My models User

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Address');
}
```

My model Addresse

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne('User');
}
```

I try to retrieve in my UsersController I try to show in my profile method the address of user
Controller Users

```
 public function profile($id){
    if($id != Auth::user()->id){
        return Redirect::to('logout');
    }
    $user=User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $address = $user->addresse;
    dd($address);
    $comments = Comment::where('user_id','=',Auth::user()->id)
        ->take(10)->get();

    return View::make('users.profile')
        ->with(array('comments'=>$comments,'address'=>$address));
}
```

But in my view I cannot retrieve the data of my relation user address.

profile.blade.php view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok you have couple errors. First you don't need to define user again because Auth::user() is already your user model. So all yo need to do is
$user = Auth::user();

and after that

```
 public function profil($id){
      ......
      $user=Auth::user();
      // this will bring users all related addresses as an array. 
      //so you can loop through and use them. 

      $adress = $user->adresses;

      ..........
 }
```

If your aim is having a single address record for each user then you should make some changes on your models.

IN your User model just add an address_id column and remove user_id column from Address table. With this way you will have one-to-one relation. Each user will only have one address.

after that in your user model remove addresses() function and add address (singular) function

```
 public function address(){
      return $this->belongsTo("Address");
 }
```

and in your Address model

```
 public function user(){
      return $this->hasOne("User");
 }
```

will give you what you need. then in your controller class

```
 public function profil($id){
      ......
      $user=Auth::user();
      $adress = $user->adress;
      // will give you a single address record belongs to user. 

      ..........
 }
```

Comment: Cool, i'm glad it solved your problem. I will appreciate if you can mark it as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your table adress delete user_id and in  table user create a row name address_id.

Change

Model user:

```
public function addresses()
{
return $this>belongsToMany('address_id','Address');
}
```

This:
    $adress = $user->address:

For this:

```
$address = $user->Address->address(name of the row with the address);
```